# Guide on Instruments in Xcode 4.2

Tags: database, sqlite, ios5, xcode4.2

Suggest any good video/tutor/book to understand how to interpret the result we get using instruments in xcode 4.2.

I want to study the memory performance of an application which will run successfully in xcode 4.2,IOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good WWDC videos on using Instruments. Here's one from 2011:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=312